# Advantage of list over string in subprocess methods

Tags: python, subprocess

What are the advantages of using list over string in subprocess methods? The ones I understand so far:

- Security if input comes from external sources
- Portability over different operating systems

Are there any others?

In my particular case, I'm using subprocess library to run tests on a software. Input does not come from external source. Tests are run only on Linux. Therefore, I see no benefit of lists over strings.

Comment: Do you mean, why pass a list as the `args` parameter to [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen), instead of a string? The documentation discusses how the input is treated differently depending on its type.

Comment: Do you mean instead of using `shell=True`?  If you use that, you *should* use a string for cross platform compatibility.  Otherwise, use a list with `shell=False`.  It avoids the overhead of spawning a shell when you don't need it, but still allows you to pass commandline arguments.

Comment: So using shell=False and parameter list as input is faster than using shell=True and string as input? So that is an additional benefit.

Comment: I suppose I can shlex.split(cmd) instead of having to create the list by myself. I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On POSIX, list and string arguments have different meaning and are used in different contexts.

You use a string argument and `shell=True` to run a shell command e.g.:

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output("dmesg | grep hda", shell=True)
```

A list argument is used to run a command without the shell e.g.:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["ls", "-l"])
```

One exception is that `call("ls")` is equivalent to `call(["ls"])` (a command with no arguments).

You should use a list argument with `shell=False` (default) except in those cases when you *need* the shell so the string argument is used.

It is almost always an error to use a list argument and `shell=True` (the arguments are interpreted as arguments to the shell itself instead of the command in this case). Don't use it.

If your question: what are the advantages of `shell=False` and hence the list argument over a string argument:

- you don't need to escape the arguments, no shell interpolation such as word splitting, parameter expansion, command substitution occurs: what you see is what you get

  - support for arguments with spaces
  - support for arguments with special characters such as quotes, dollar sign, etc
- it is clear where arguments boundaries are. They are explicitely separated.
- it is clear what program is executed: it is the first item in the list
- an argument that is populated from an untrusted source won't be able to execute arbitrary commands
- why run a superfluous shell process unless you need it

Sometimes, it might be more convenient/readable to specify an argument as a string in the source code; `shlex.split()` could be used to convert it to a list:

```
import shlex
from subprocess import check_call

cmd = shlex.split('/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" '
                  '''-cmd "echo '$MONEY'"''')
check_call(cmd)
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

---

On Windows, the arguments are interpreted differently. The native format is a string and the passed list is converted to a string using `subprocess.list2cmdline()` function that may not work for all Windows programs. `shell=True` is only necessary to run builtin shell commands.

If `list2cmdline()` creates a correct command line for your executable (different programs may use different rules for interpreting the command line) then a list argument could be used for portability and to avoid escaping separate arguments manually.