# how to print subprocess' stdout directly to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

How do I force subprocess.Popen/os.Popen to write large output directly to file, without holding anything in the buffer ?
I tried this:

```
os.popen(cmd, bufsize=0)
```

it didn`t help.
Any solution of reading all the output (again, large output) and saving it to file/list would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `stdout` parameter to redirect output from a subprocess to a file:

```
import shlex
from subprocess import check_call

with open('outputfilename', 'wb', 0) as outputfile:
    check_call(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=outputfile)
```

> Do you know what I should add to the command to prevent the subprocess from printing warning/errors to the shell ?

Just set `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to merge stdout/stderr. Or redirect `stderr` to `os.devnull` to discard the output.

Comment: this helped! but `shlex.split(cmd)` was wrong. I changed it with the string cmd (`cmd = "ls dir"`) and it worked. thanks.
Do you know what I should add to the command to prevent the subprocess  from printing warning/errors to the shell ?

Comment: no, `check_call("ls dir", stdout=outputfile)` fails. You want `shlex.split("ls dir") == ["ls", "dir"]` instead. Do not use `shell=True` unless you need it. Provide explicit list argument. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22614070/4279)

Comment: `raise child_exception`
`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`
this is what i`m getting when giving it a list.

Comment: `cmd = command.split(" ")`
`check_call(cmd, stdout=outputfile)` 
the second line

Comment: using shlex.split() is not helping. the command is calling another script.

Comment: @user2234234: I don't believe it. Unless you are on Windows the string argument should fail. What happens if you pass `shlex.split(command)`? If you can't tell the actual value of `command` then what its general structure (spaces, `$`, quotes `'"` are important) e.g., `"cmd -o 'arg 1' '$arg2'"`

Comment: the command is something like this: `script.pl -val_a a -val_b b -flag1 -flag2`. it has nothing special and i`m under unix.

Comment: `check_call(shlex.split("script.pl -val_a a -val_b b -flag1 -flag2"), stdout=outputfile)` should work if `script.pl` is in `PATH` and it has proper shebang (`#!..`) and it has proper file permissions (`chmod +x ..`)

Comment: script.pl is in PATH and it has proper shebang (#!..) and it has proper file permissions (chmod +x ..), but still not working! it`s OK man, thank you.

Comment: @user2234234: If it doesn't work; I want to know why. It may help others. Are sure that you haven't sneaked `shell=True`?

Comment: What happens if you call: `check_call('script.pl')` (no other arguments) in the same script? What is your Python version?

Answer (score 2):

This is how to redirect `stdout` to a file:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('your_file', 'w')
```

Then everything that would have outputted in the shell is dumped in that file.

Comment: It didn`t work. the process is printing ~500 lines to the file and holds the rest in buffer. when I kill the script, it write the rest to the file.

Comment: You can reopen the `stdout` file descriptor with write mode, and 0 as the buffer size (so unbuffered). `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)`.

Comment: replacing `sys.stdout` does not redirect the output from a subprocess to the file. You need either use `stdout` parameter of a subprocess or [redirect stdout at file descriptor level, see `stdout_redirected()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)